Are the changes of Upanyanam regarding age actually recorded?
So, many people argue the age of Rama and Sita are older since both got their Upanyanam and were Dvijas? I am wondering if going through studentship actually changes the age as some people mentioned or is this just nonsense?

Can you explain a bit more? not clear to me what you are asking

@Rickross sure is ages like that of Rams measured after his Upanyanam and Dvija or twice born ceremony or before?
